# Retorno de codigo de status de requisição

Tags: c#, json

Estou realizando um post para uma API de terceiros mas gostaria de obter o código de retorno da mesma para salvar em nosso banco, entretanto, só consigo obter esse codigo de retorno se o código for 202, caso fosse 401 ou 500 ele me retorna null, eu necessito que retorne qualquer codigo de retorno e não null.

```
public static RetornoRequisicao HttpRequestJson(string token, string url, string dados)
    {

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
        string retorno;
        int status;
        try
        {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {

                string json = dados;

                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();

                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                status = (int)httpResponse.StatusCode;

                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    retorno = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

            return new RetornoRequisicao
            {
                retorno = retorno,
                status = status
            };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução ->

```
    public static RetornoRequisicao HttpRequestJson(string token, string url, string dados)
    {

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
        string retorno;
        int status;
        try
        {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {

                string json = dados;

                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();

                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                status = (int)httpResponse.StatusCode;

                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    retorno = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            retorno = "Erro ao enviar Json";
            status = (int)((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode;
        }

        return new RetornoRequisicao
        {
            retorno = retorno,
            status = status
        };

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você não pode ter um valor nulo ali, associe ele à algum número usando o operador ternário `?:`.

```
            ...
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            status = (httpResponse != null ? (int)httpResponse.StatusCode : 500);

            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                retorno = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            ...
```

Assim, se `request.GetResponse()` for `null`, será admitido `(int)500` no lugar dele em `status`.

Comment: esta seria uma "boa" alternativa mas seria gambiarrada, minha intenção é trazer realmente o código do status e não um código aleatório, obtive null com o código 500, mas poderia dar 404, 401 e etc..

Comment: Fiz um código que retorna um status aleatório porque você especificou na tua pergunta: _eu necessito que retorne qualquer codigo de retorno e não null._

Answer (score 0):

Quando o servidor retorna um erro, como o 500, é lançada uma exceção do tipo WebException. Então para pegar o código do erro utilize um um try/catch. Exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Vai retornar um erro 500
        var url = "http://www.mocky.io/v2/5d8d0b982e0000db0dabde95";

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "get";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        try 
        {
            var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            // Vai printar ProtocolError neste exemplo
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Status);
        }
    }
}
```

[Link da documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?view=netframework-4.8)

> The WebRequest class throws a WebException when errors occur while
>   accessing an Internet resource. The Status property is one of the
>   WebExceptionStatus values that indicates the source of the error. When
>   Status is WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError, the Response property
>   contains the WebResponse received from the Internet resource.

Comment: Só colocar ex.Status não resolveu, encontrei uma solução melhor na internet que utiliza esta linha ->  (int)((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode;